# Cross origin Node js in Cloud 9 ide

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I have a client in a workspace and server side in the another workspace.

I have Cross orgin in the server workspace.

```
res.header('Access-Conrol-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
```

But While calling from the client side getting below error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blogclient-vignesh55.c9users.io/?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io#/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://10.237.69.147:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=18446744072714596624'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is not the Same Origin Policy, but that your page is mixing `http` and `https` calls. Make sure to either use protocol-independent urls like `//someurl.com` or that you only use one protocol throughout your project.

PS: If you actually read the error message, it tells you exactly this:

> the content must be served over HTTPS

and you try to call it via `http`:

> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=XXX

Comment: I have a doubt. 
While previewing server side url preview: https://ionicserver-****/. So i am trying to use the URL in the client side. How to overcome the mixed issue whether i have to create a server in the https and link

Comment: I have no clue, what you are try to tell/ask me, but the error message you presented is pretty clear.